# How to find the sizeof array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

### How to find the sizeof  an  array, by  a function which receives only  a pointer to  the array?

---

```
    int find(int *p)
{  
// I want  to find  the  sizeof  
//   the array in this function  


    return 1;  
}

    int main()

{

    int a[]={12,2,9,6,5,11,15};
    find(a);

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: wlcome to SO! always add at least a language or library tag if your question has code.

Comment: You don't have a "pointer to the array". A *pointer to the array* would be like `int (*p)[7]`. You have a *pointer to an int*.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you pass the size of the array you can't do it. If, in your case, -1 is a sentinel marking the end of the list you can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(int *p)
{  
    int * q = p;
    while(*q != -1)
        ++q;
    return q-p;  
}

int main()
{

    int a[]={12,2,9,6,5,11,-1};
    printf("%d", find(a));

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: i did not understand..
int *q =p;
why did u  use it??
and also why did you  return q-p??

Comment: If -1 only appears at the end of the array, and always appears at the end of the array, then the code I supplied will return the count of items.

Comment: ok. but why are  you returning q-p??

Comment: *q is a shorthand for q[0]. Since q keeps increasing through the loop you're testing q[0], q[1], q[2], etc. which is like testing a[0], a[1], a[2] until you get the place in the array where -1 occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just passing a pointer with no size information to `find` then you have to have to use something like the `C` `char*` string idiom and have a special end-of-data value.  `C`'s string idiom uses the `null` character (`\0`) mark the end-of-data.  `C`'s standard length-of-string function (`strlen`) also doesn't include this `null` character in the count of the size of the string.  It looks like the above code may be using `-1` to mark the end of data.  This will work if you never use negative values for data.  If this is the case, then you can calculate the size of array like this:

```
size_t length_of_array(int *p) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while( *(p + len) > 0 )
        ++len;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: i have not used -1 as end, if i  dont know the last character, how to proceed??

Comment: You can't. You are passing a pointer, not an array, and there's no way to get the number of elements of an array given a pointer a pointer to the array. Is there an *actual* problem you're trying to solve?